# Measuring time between keys clicked

Tags: c#

When I'm clicking W/A/S/D on keyobard, it doesn't measure time between two keys clicked, but all of time. Here is my complete code:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                stopwatch1.Start();
            }
            private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "W (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "A (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.S)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "S (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "D (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
            }
            private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                stopwatch1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```

Example output:

```
W (560) + A (634) + S (753) + D (846) + A (944) +
```

And what I wanna is for example:

```
W (560) + A (128) + S (82)
```

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time believing this hasn't been asked before, but you could either use `stopwatch1.StartNew();` instead of `stopwatch1.Start();` or after `stopwatch1.Stop();` you could use `stopwatch1.Reset();`

The problem is when you stop and then start again, the previous value is still loaded in the stopwatch.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand, what your mean with your question.
But I#m thinking your problem hangs together with the KeyPress method.
You have to now that the events you use will trigger as follows:
KeyDown i if you Press the button Down
KeyUp if you release
And KeyPress triggers also if you release.

You have to Events which collides. KeyUp & KeyPress. Maybe you try it some way like this:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                stopwatch1.Start();
            }
            private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.W)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "W (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.A)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "A (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.S)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "S (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.D)
                {
                    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + "D (" + stopwatch1.ElapsedMilliseconds + ") + ";
                }
                stopwatch1.Stop();
            }
        }
    }
```